# Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute

Tags: android, xml

¿Por qué este 'error'? No tengo ningún atributo duplicado.
¿Cuál es la solución?

**MENSAJE ERROR**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*activity_commerce.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".view.CommerceActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/commerce_fragment"
    android:name=".view.CommerceFragment"
    class=".view.CommerceFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_commerce" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*fragment_commerce.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".view.CommerceActivity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ver_fragment_commerce_relative_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/description_block_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ver_fragment_commerce_relative_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/description_fragment_commerce"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/description_switch_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/description_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:checked="false"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_description_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_below="@id/description_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:hint="..."
            android:padding="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/schedule_block_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/description_block_relative_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/schedule_fragment_commerce"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switch_schedule_image_button_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_circle_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorGreyAndroid"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/now_schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Hoy 9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_below="@id/now_schedule_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:hint="Lunes:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30\nMartes:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30\nMiércoles:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30\nJueves:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30\nViernes:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30\nSábado:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30\nDomingo:\t9:00-13:00, 17:00-20:30"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_slider_block_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/schedule_block_relative_layout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/foo_temporal_image_slider_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:hint="IMÁGENES EN SLIDER"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/general_info_block_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_slider_block_relative_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address_fragment_commerce"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="foo direccion"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phone_number_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_below="@+id/address_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="foo phone"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/email_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_number_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="foo mail"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/web_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/web_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_below="@id/email_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_web_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="foo web"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/web_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/web_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/web_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/social_networks__block_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/general_info_block_relative_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/social_networks_text_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/social_networks_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_facebook"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/twitter_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/twitter_image_view_fragment_commerce"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_twitter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/facebook_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/instagram_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/instagram_image_view_fragment_commerce"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/instagram_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_instagram"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/facebook_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/google_plus_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/google_plus_image_view_fragment_commerce"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/google_plus_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_google_plus"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/facebook_image_view_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/google_maps__block_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@id/social_networks__block_relative_layout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/foo_temporal_google_maps_fragment_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:hint="GOOGLE MAPS DEL COMERCIO"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--<RelativeLayout-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/extras__block_relative_layout"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_below="@id/google_maps__block_relative_layout">-->

    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Deberías añadir la solución como respuesta en lugar de como edición.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En cuanto a tu pregunta recuerda que en `Android` **dentro de un `Layout`, únicamente debes contener un `namespace`**, en este caso:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 2):

El 'error' está en el fichero fragment_commerce.xml

> Eliminar en ScrollView: *xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"*